# I need to find know how to integrate $x$ multiplied by a function to a power that is a fraction.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I know how to find integral functions normally, but when I try to find it from say $x\sqrt{4-x^2}$, I get completely lost.This screws me up in both indefinite and definite integration, so please help

Comment: There are several standard "tricks" generally applicable, your textbook should elaborate. But keep in mind that some inocuous-looking integrals just can't be written in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

We have our integral:
$$\int x\sqrt{4-x^2} \ dx$$
We can use u-substitution for this integral. Let:
$$u=4-x^2$$
$$du=-2x \ dx$$
Now we can rewrite the integral:
$$\int -\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{u} \ du$$
$$=-\dfrac{1}{2}\int u^{1/2} \ du$$
$$=-\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2u^{3/2}}{3}+C$$
$$=-\dfrac{u^{3/2}}{3}+C$$
Reversing the substitution:
$$-\dfrac{(4-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}+C$$
$$-\dfrac{\sqrt{(4-x^2)^3}}{3}+C$$
$$\therefore \int x\sqrt{4-x^2}=-\dfrac{\sqrt{(4-x^2)^3}}{3}+C$$